# Preference view on android not being a fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

For the preference view, I have seen examples where its created an activity, then its created a PreferenceFragment and put it inside the new activity.

1. Why the preference view has to be a fragment and not just the layout for the new activity without it being a fragment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only create and activity when you need, first think about it.

Rule #1
Create an Activity only if it's absolutely absolutely required.

In this case if you think in details, you dont need to use an new Activity, the practical and best way is load a fragment.